# Identify season date ranges

Tags: datetime, time-series

I thought this question would be pretty common but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

I have a dataframe with observations gathered between 1st of January 2008, until 31st of December 2021. I wanted to highlight the season in which each observation was gathered.

I wanted to have a variable that states "Spring" if the observations falls into that date range.

I think it would be quite straightforward if I only have one year since I can directly aim for the one particular date range. However, in my case I am looking at something more general like: from = "%Y-03-21", to = "%Y-06-20". So I want to highlight each observation, regardless of year, that falls into that category?

How do I do that?

I had one pseudo approach (which I know is not right) but it was an attempt to express what I wanted:

`df$spring <- ifelse(df$date %in% seq.Date(from = "%Y-03-21", to = "%Y-06-20"), "Spring", "other")`

Is my problem so special or am I just not able to find the trivial answer?

small note: each date has more than one observation (if that matters at all). My df looks something like:

`df <- data.frame(date = c("2008-01-01","2008-01-01","2008-01-01","2008-01-02","2008-01-02"), count = c(9,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/find-the-season-for-a-date-6fda7a8230bb